# How to implement so that Typescript in Nuxt 2 does not swear?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

do user authorization

made the auth class

```
    import type { Context } from '@nuxt/types';
    
    export class Auth {
      public ctx: Context;
    
      constructor(ctx: Context) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
      }
    
      async login(data: any): Promise<any> {
        return await this.ctx.app.$projectServices.repository.login(data);
      }
    
      async fetchUser() {
        return await this.ctx.app.$projectServices.repository.getAuthUser();
      }
    }

created a plugin for injecting the global variable $auth

    import { Plugin } from '@nuxt/types';
    
    import { Auth } from '~/services/auth/auth';
    
    const auth: Plugin = (context, inject) => {
      const auth = new Auth(context);
    
      inject('auth', auth);
    };

export default auth;
```

when initializing the naxt, I check for the presence of a token in localStorage, and if so, I make a request to get user data

nuxtClientInit plugin

```
export default async function (context: any) {
  await context.store.dispatch('nuxtClientInit');
}
```

store

```
import { getToken } from '~/services/auth/token';

export const actions = {
  async nuxtClientInit({ commit }: any) {
    const token = getToken();
    if (token) {
      commit('auth/setToken', { token });
      await this.$auth
        .fetchUser()
        .then((response: any) => {
          commit('setItem', response);
        })
        .catch((e: any) => {
          if (e.status === 401) {
            commit('auth/clear');
          }
        });
    }
  },
};
```

in the store swears at this.$auth

TS2339: Property '$auth' does not exist on type '{ nuxtClientInit({ commit }: any): Promise ; }'

how to solve a problem?

Comment: Could disable TS if you're not using it.

Answer (score 0):

add this to the types array in your `tsconfig.json`

```
"types": [
      "@nuxt/types", 
      "@nuxtjs/auth" // Add this line
    ]
```

if for that some reason fails, add the type manually in `types/vue-shim.d.ts`

```
import { Auth } from 'nuxtjs__auth'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    // ...
    readonly $auth: Auth
  }
}
```